# Pyodbc : SQLExecDirectW error while insert

Tags: python, pyodbc

For some reason, I am storing the below array completely in the SQL server using **pyodbc** in the form of text with single quotes.

> ['Sachin', 'Yuvraj']

I am inserting the above value using below code

```
tes_table= SQLCURSOR.execute('''INSERT INTO Test_Table(test_name) VALUES ('{}')
                                '''.format(arr))
```

I am getting the below error.

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Sachin'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[13/Oct/2020 23:54:53] "POST /api/save HTTP/1.1" 500 77431
```

Comment: So you want to insert a single row where the `test_name` column contains the string `['Sachin', 'Yuvraj']`. Is that correct?

Comment: the array value should in one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another example of why using string formatting to embed data *values* into SQL command text is a bad idea. In this case the rendered string literal creates a syntax error because the single quotes are not properly escaped.

```
>>> arr = ['Sachin', 'Yuvraj']
>>> "... VALUES ('{}')".format(arr)
"... VALUES ('['Sachin', 'Yuvraj']')"
```

Instead, you should be using a proper *parameterized query*

```
sql = """\
INSERT INTO Test_Table (test_name) VALUES (?)
"""
tes_table = SQLCURSOR.execute(sql, str(arr))
```